# how to use variable in rdlc c# mysql?

Tags: mysql, rdlc

I have this table

```
+------------+------------+
| debt       | credit     |
+------------+------------+
|     10.00  |      0.00  |
|      0.00  |     10.00  | 
|     20.00  |      0.00  |
|     10.00  |      0.00  |
|      0.00  |      5.00  |
|      0.00  |      2.00  |
|     10.00  |      0.00  |
|      0.00  |     25.00  |
|    100.00  |     0.000  |
+------------+------------+
```

I would like to calculate balance field by this expression:balance=(debt-credit)+balance`
in my report rdlc

```
+------------+------------+---------+
| debt       | credit     | balance |
+------------+------------+---------+
|     10.00  |      0.00  | 10.00   |
|      0.00  |     10.00  |  0.00   |
|     20.00  |      0.00  | 20.00   |
|     10.00  |      0.00  | 30.00   |
|      0.00  |      5.00  | 25.00   |
|      0.00  |      2.00  | 23.00   |
|     10.00  |      0.00  | 33.00   |
|      0.00  |     25.00  |  8.00   |
|    100.00  |     0.000  |108.00   |
+------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. This problem is technically insoluble (although there are hacks)

Comment: You have a table, How are you retrieving it to run the RDLC... VB, C#?  Into a list<someDataStructure> or via DataTable/DataRow?

Comment: C# and using DataTable .